# Eclipse Java: Eclipse complains of missing curly brace in class

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-error

the following code in eclipse gives a "}" missing in classbody when in eclipse, but compiles perfectly well from the terminal. Any clues?

```
package quiz;

    public class Session {
        static int currentQuestion = 0;
        private Sentence[] sentences; // for building questions
        private Question[] questions;

        public void generateReport(Session publishSession) {

        }

        public int  getRightQuestionCount() {

        }

        public int getWrongQuestionCount() {

        }

        public int calculatePercent() {

        }
        public Question getQuestionAtIdx(int index) {
            return questions[index];
        }
        public Question getPreviousQuestion() {
            return getQuestionAtIdx(--currentQuestion);
        }
        public Question getNextQuestion() {
            return getQuestionAtIdx(--currentQuestion);
        }


        public void setQuestionAtIdx(int index, Question) {

        } 
    }
```

Comment: Try to cut and paste the code or clean the project. In many cases Eclipse then recognizes the non-error. :)

Comment: Also, the getPreviouseQuestion() method paints "--currentQuestion" blue, but the method after it, getNextQuestion, doesn't. The last } has an error on it saying I should delete this token

Comment: @Asaf.. look at the updated answer..

Comment: `... but compiles perfectly well from the terminal` - all the errors the others pointed out should not allow you to do that, are you sure the code you posted is the same that you compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toward the end, you're declaring a function with two parameters; for the second parameter you specified the type, but no name. Maybe that's it.

```
public void setQuestionAtIdx(int index, Question <<missing name>>) {

}
```

Comment: Good job, I can't believe the kind of mistakes I make. Does it make sense that the command line javac didn't call this one?

Comment: Like I said, sometimes I can't believe I got stuck on something like this. Thanks to everybody, but JeffreyHammansson nailed it first...

Answer (score 1):

that last method

```
public void setQuestionAtIdx(int index, Question/*has a missing arguement but only its type*/) {

        }
```

so add

```
public void setQuestionAtIdx(int index, Question question) {

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is here:

`public void setQuestionAtIdx(int index, Question) {        }`

`Question` has no identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse sometimes gets confused.  If the code is syntactically correct, try restarting eclipse.

your code as you pasted above will not compile due to several issues, notably missing parameter names and return values as mentioned above.